# moment.js - how to prevent daylight saving from changing the date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

When I pass a date to moment, if the date happen to be the day when DST changes, and if DST time of change is exactly 12:00 AM, moment.js will shift the time and causing the date to change.

For example, in Chile/Santiago time zone, DST start at 9/6/2020 at 0 hour (or 12:00 AM).
If I run `moment('2020-09-06')` it will return *9/5/2020 11:00 PM*.
So `moment('2020-09-06').format('MM/DD/YYYY')` returns *09/05/2020* instead of *09/06/2020*

The way I deal with it is to append an arbitrary time to the date so that the date stays in the same date even if it is shifted by an hour.  Is there a better way using moment.js to handle this case (without using other js library)?

Comment: The thing is, that's the correct behavior.

Comment: I think a date without time should just be treated as a date without time, but I know moment will treat it as the date at 0:00 o'clock.  If I give moment the date "9/6/2020" and it gives me back "9/5/2020" it's just not quite right.

Comment: Well, time is an extremely complicated topic.

Comment: Thing is, if I pass the date `9/6/2020` to a function and ask the function to give me back the long date description, I should receive `September 6th, 2020`, and not `September 5th, 2020`, if you know what I mean.  I am not blaming moment.js here, just try to find a better way to handle this corner case.

Comment: Moment is based on the underlying behavior of the JavaScript date mechanism. There are all sorts of weird things that can happen based on time zone etc.